# Are objects repelled by the cosmological horizon in Lambda-CDM cosmology?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, gravitational-redshift, emergent-properties

When an observer watches a distant object, is there a gravitational influence of the horizon on that object? ("Distant" here is meant to mean: at a distance that is a sizeable fraction of the Hubble radius $L$. Lambda-CDM is assumed.)

1. Does the distant object feel a **repulsion** from the cosmological horizon?
2. Does the distant object feel an **attraction** towards the cosmological horizon?
3. Does the distant object feel **no effect** from the cosmological horizon?

(Verlinde's paper from 2016, where he discusses the cosmological acceleration $a_0=c^2/L$ in the light of emergent gravity, suggests this question.) The question is about Lambda-CDM cosmology, not anything else.

Comment: By readings of Nikodem J Poplawski's "cosmology with torsion" in various papers he's posted on Arxiv between 2009 and 2019, I've had an impression that local universes formed within causal separations (gravitational horizons) would be of smaller scale, that halves of pairs of particles until then only virtual would be materialized upon their tidal separation (by such a horizon, which would propagate outward from the center of a large rotating star collapsing gravitationally), and that the materialized particles would fill an expanding 3-D zone.  Would this resemble your visualized scenario?

Comment: No, the question is about usual cosmology. With one universe.

Answer (score 1):

No effect. In the simplest case of uniform, isotropic expansion, all objects recede from one another with a velocity proportional to their proper separation.  There is no force.

During accelerated expansion, there is a cosmological horizon. But the horizon is not an absolute thing---it is relative to the observer. So an object that I observe to be receding from me at a great distance might be near my horizon, but of course very far from it’s own. So there is no sense in which my horizon should have any influence on other objects.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Verlinde suggests such an effect. It is clear that the effect is small, if it exists ...

Comment: I think you are misreading Verlinde.  What I've written above is standard.  What precisely is Verlinde saying that contradicts my answer?

Comment: Verlinde says in his 2016 paper that the horizon leads to an acceleration c^2/R (where R is roughly the radius of the universe) that that this leads to what we usually think of as "dark matter effects". So he says that "dark matter" is an effect of the horizon.

Comment: He doesn’t literally mean that the observer’s horizon itself has any direct effect on matter. How could it? Me and someone else in Andromeda have different horizons: which one does some matter out by M87 care about? What he’s saying is that the de Sitter expansion leads to an acceleration of matter ( in the sense that recession velocities have positive time derivatives); since de Sitter expansion necessarily possesses a horizon, he is using the two interchangeably.